# Неполный вывод данных в REST.API

Tags: php, api, rest, битрикс24

Решается такая задача, делаю вывод задач из Битрикс24.
Команда на то используется `task.planner.getlist`. Все это обернул в свою функцию класса:

```
$url = 'https://'.$newObj->domain.'/rest/task.items.getlist?auth='.$newObj->access_token;
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$response = $newObj->call_public($data);

public function call_public($data)
{    
      $array_res = get_object_vars(json_decode($data));      
      return $array_res;        
}
```

И почему-то оно выводит только 50 записей, больше не хочет, хотя там их более 200 задач. В чем проблема? Кто с подобным сталкивался?

Answer (score 3):

> PARAMS    Массив для опций вызова. Элементом является массив NAV_PARAMS вида {"опция вызова": 'значение' [, ...]}, хранящий следующие опции:
>
> - **nPageSize** - количество элементов на странице. В целях ограничения нагрузки на постраничную навигацию наложено ограничение в 50 задач.
> - **iNumPage** - номер страницы при постраничной навигации.

http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/tasks/task/item/list.php

Очевидно, вам нужно получать следующую страницу до тех пор, пока вам не будет возвращено 404, пустой массив или вы не наберете в буфере необходимое количество задач.